# Apache Ignite .Net Core failed to start

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Apache ignite .net core server node fails to start with below error, any idea what could be the reason?

```
Apache.Ignite.Core.Binary.BinaryObjectException
HResult = -2146233088,
Message = Unexpected field type [pos=42559, expected=String, actual=0]  
StackTrace:
class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Unexpected field type [pos=42559, expected=String, actual=0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.checkFlagNoHandles(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1684)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readString(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1058)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.utils.PlatformConfigurationUtils.readDataRegionConfiguration(PlatformConfigurationUtils.java:2303)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.utils.PlatformConfigurationUtils.readDataStorageConfiguration(PlatformConfigurationUtils.java:2082)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.utils.PlatformConfigurationUtils.readIgniteConfiguration(PlatformConfigurationUtils.java:919)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.dotnet.PlatformDotNetConfigurationClosure.processPrepareResult(PlatformDotNetConfigurationClosure.java:195)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.dotnet.PlatformDotNetConfigurationClosure.prepare(PlatformDotNetConfigurationClosure.java:182)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.dotnet.PlatformDotNetConfigurationClosure.apply0(PlatformDotNetConfigurationClosure.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformAbstractConfigurationClosure.apply(PlatformAbstractConfigurationClosure.java:50)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformAbstractConfigurationClosure.apply(PlatformAbstractConfigurationClosure.java:27)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformAbstractBootstrap.start(PlatformAbstractBootstrap.java:40)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformIgnition.start(PlatformIgnition.java:74)
```

*NOTE:This error only occuring in Apache Ignite 2.12.0 and code working fine in the previous versions.*

Answer (score 0):

An error like this happens due to a mismatch of .NET binaries and Java jar files.

Try deleting `bin` and `obj` directories and performing a clean rebuild.